# Error: Text date with 2 digit year

Tags: microsoft-excel

For some reason the dates I enter into my Excel 2013 spreadsheet show up with "Error: Text date with 2 digit year" for other Excel user on another computer.

This breaks some formulas in my colleague's own Excel 2013 spreadsheet because he does some date calculations in his.

I type with English (United State) or English (Canada) and French (Canada). Colleague types with English (Canada) only.

The format of dates we use is 07-02-15 which is equivalent to today's date. 
I checked both Excels and both dates are of Date format.

I seem to be the only one as there's another person with French layout and their dates are of same format yet they don't show the Error like mine do.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Excel is not actually storing your dates as dates.  It is storing them as strings.  Would you try changing the field format to date?

Comment: No, they are all date. But I checked, and my location is set to French (Canada) and everyone else to English(Canada). I switched to that too and now dates seem to work properly.

Comment: If it works then no need to fix it further.  I mentioned the string because of the message you posted about "...Text date...".  Excel should be storing the date as a number and converting it to the selected display format, not keeping it as a string, but whatever.